# Install using yum without root permissions

Tags: package-management, non-root-user

So I don't have root permissions but I've been installing packages to a local directory on my (CentOS) system and it works fine.

But I was wondering if I can do the same using `yum`. The reason I want to use `yum` is because I don't want to worry about dependencies and want `yum` to take care of that for me.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/29646/11539), [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/31129/11539) and specially [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5535/11539); while these questions might look pretty different, I think they are not (at least their answers are relevant here).  Oh, and there is [**this**](http://superuser.com/q/198674/102592), indicating that there might be a solution using `yumdownloader` and `rpm --relocate`.

Comment: I am not sure if `yum localinstall` has a preview mode that can be used by non-privileged users as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible. If you have `sudo` rights, you could run `sudo yum <...>`.

Comment: This is true, but I'm pretty sure "I don't have root permissions" means he's not a sudoer